# certbot issue with Openssl in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

Im unable to renew my ssl-certificate via certbot,When i run certbot command it says :

```
AttributeError: cffi library '_openssl' has no function, constant or global variable named 'Cryptography_HAS_MEM_FUNCTIONS'
```

**Below my setup described  :**

Ubuntu version :

```
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
```

Openssl Version :

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
```

python and cryptography version :

```
root@testingvm:~# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Mar  1 2021, 11:38:31) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cryptography
>>> cryptography.__version__
'1.9'
```

When i try to dry-run the certbot cert renewal command :

root@testingvm:# certbot renew --dry-run

```
root@testingvm:# certbot renew --dry-run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.31.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    import josepy as jose
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/josepy/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from josepy.interfaces import JSONDeSerializable
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/josepy/interfaces.py", line 8, in <module>
    from josepy import errors, util
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/josepy/util.py", line 4, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 156, in <module>
    Binding.init_static_locks()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 137, in init_static_locks
    cls._ensure_ffi_initialized()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 124, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
    cls.lib = build_conditional_library(lib, CONDITIONAL_NAMES)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 84, in build_conditional_library
    if not getattr(lib, condition):
AttributeError: cffi library '_openssl' has no function, constant or global variable named 'Cryptography_HAS_MEM_FUNCTIONS'
```

Comment: I think the Python **cryptography** package is out of date. Which version do you have installed? Was the package installed by **apt** or **pip**? Verify that your configuration is still supported: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#supported-platforms

Comment: updated version of cryptography & default python above

Comment: You have an old version of cryptography. Update your system.